# SAP Analytics Cloud - CI/CD over azure devOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd, sap-analytics-cloud

Is it possible to software manage deployments for **SAP Analytics Cloud** over pipelines in Azure devops?

Comment: you could refer to the steps in this [sap blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/01/25/build-a-ci-cd-pipeline-in-azure-devops-and-connect-it-to-sap-cloud-foundry/) to create the integration between Azure DevOps and SAP Analytics Cloud.

Comment: hi @CeenoQi-MSFT, good point. In the shown sap blog, they were using the mta build tool. How can i get the sources from SAP Analytics Cloud as input for the MTA build tool?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT no i don't right now. Im doubting where to find all required inputsources for the local build. is it only the content i get over SACs webide > export, or do i need to grab anything else for the build?

Comment: Hi Maier, any update?

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT, oh yes, that's my issue. I'm gonna try and come back later

Comment: Hi Maier, any update?

Answer (score 0):

Maier

During the investigations and reference, I found this doc to build the [integration to SAP Analytics Cloud](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAC_EMBEDDED_EDITION/8c9fe042688a4354876cc536267d442f/87f2958b9cc544c3a57851dd1b78ee75.html) from `CF Cli`.

From Azure DevOps side, I managed to create the `CF Cli` environment ([doc reference](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/cf-cli/install-go-cli.html#pkg)) with the **yaml pipeline** below.

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest


steps:
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      wget -q -O - https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian/cli.cloudfoundry.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
      echo "deb https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list
```

**Or via classic pipeline editor.**

```
wget -q -O - https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian/cli.cloudfoundry.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://packages.cloudfoundry.org/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list
```

[image]

With the `CF Cli` commands, you could also set up other integrations to SAP Analytics Cloud.

Hope this procedure could help you with the integration, and if you are looking for methods for other type of source, you could also share with me.